# Get related list information from an Object

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, custom-object

I have an object called position__c and skill_profile__c. I have a juntion object - position_skill_set__c , which is a junction object between postion__c and skill_profile__c. The junction object appears as a related list on position__c. I am trying to get the name of the juntion object like - position_skill_set__c.Name. here is my trigger:

```
trigger CopySkillsToProject on Position__c (after update) {

    for (Position__c position: Trigger.new) {

        System.debug('Position is -' + position.Name + ' ' + position.Postion__r.);

    }
}
```

I am creating this trigger to perform some operation when the position is updated( which I have not implemented yet) , before that I want to access the junction object name inside the trigger. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you query for the related objects, the trigger won't have any values for related objects. So, you'll need to do something like this:

```
trigger CopySkillsToProject on Position__c (after update) {

   map<ID,Position__c> posIdToPositionMap = new map<ID,Position> (
                           [select id, 
                               (select id, name from Position_skill_sets__r)
                               from Position__c where id IN :Trigger.new]);


   for (Position__c p : Trigger.new)
       for (Position_Skill_Set__c pss : posIdToPositionMap.get(p.id).position_skill_sets__r)
           system.debug(pss.name);  // name of the jth PSR on the ith Position
}
```